# Formato incorrecto al generar JSON en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Tengo problema al crear una array para pasarlo a formato JSON.

Al recorrer el resultado de una consulta en la base de datos, asigno los valores a un array. Tras esto, formateo el JSON poniendo una cabecera a la lista de valores.

El problema es que por algún motivo aparece un corchete de más, esto hace que luego el código html no funcione correctamente.

Éste es mi código PHP:

```php
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
$response["MIGRUPO"] = array();

$resultUsuario = mysql_query("SELECT ID_GRUPO, 
                                     HORA
                                FROM GRUPOS");   

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultUsuario)) {
    $arr[$i]['ID_GRUPO'] = $row['ID_GRUPO'];
    $arr[$i]['HORA'] = $row['HORA'];
    $i++;
}

array_push($response['MIGRUPO'], $arr);
$json_response = json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_response;
```

Este es el JSON que devuelve

```
"MIGRUPO":[
[
{
"ID_GRUPO":"1",
"HORA":"20:30:00"
},
{
"ID_GRUPO":"2",
"HORA":"20:30:00"
},
{
"ID_GRUPO":"3",
"HORA":"19:30:00"
},
{
"ID_GRUPO":"4",
"HORA":"18:30:00"
}
]
]
}
```

Sin embargo si filtro la consulta para que sólo devuelva un registro y sólo asigno valores a una posición del array (quitando el $i), el JSON si se formatea correctamente.

¿Alguien puede ver por qué se genera una dimensión de más?

Comment: al principio del JSON falta un `{`, lo olvidasde de copiar o ese es el problema? El resto del JSON esta como lo construye el programa. ¿Como esperas que se el output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede evitar una dimensión en el array cambiando esta línea:

```php
array_push($response['MIGRUPO'], $arr);
```

en la que se está agregando todo el array de resultados como un único item del array `MIGRUPO`, por lo siguiente:

```php
$response['MIGRUPO'] = $arr;
```

en donde a `MIGRUPO` se le asigna directamente el array de resultados `$arr`.

Resultado:

```
{
    "MIGRUPO": [
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "1",
            "HORA": "20:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "2",
            "HORA": "20:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "3",
            "HORA": "19:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "4",
            "HORA": "18:30:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

<kbd>[Demo en rextester.com](http://rextester.com/VVRN36522)</kbd>

Comment: Perfecto esa el problema, ya he conseguido sacar el output que necesitaba. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

el doble array lo generas en:

```
array_push($response['MIGRUPO'], $arr);
```

el código limpio sería:

```
$response['MIGRUPO'] = array();
// No es necesario inicializar variables en PHP, sin embargo, es una muy
// buena práctica. Las variables no inicializadas tienen un valor 
// predeterminado de acuerdo a su tipo dependiendo del contexto en el 
// que son usadas
$resultUsuario = mysql_query('SELECT id_grupo, hora FROM grupos');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultUsuario)) {
    $response['MIGRUPO'][] = array('ID_GRUPO' => $row['id_grupo'], 'HORA' => $row['hora']);
}
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

obteniendo:

```
{
    "MIGRUPO": [
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "1",
            "HORA": "20:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "2",
            "HORA": "20:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "3",
            "HORA": "19:30:00"
        },
        {
            "ID_GRUPO": "4",
            "HORA": "18:30:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Saludos